# ¿Cómo traducir "to draw first blood"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Entiendo el concepto detrás de la expresión "to draw first blood": "golpear/herir primero [al oponente]."

Como ejemplo, estoy pensando específicamente en la letra de la canción "Blaze of Glory" de Bon Jovi:

> Lord I never drew first
>
> But I drew first blood

¿Pero hay algún término o expresión más precisa que denote lo mismo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En español existe y se usa la traducción directa: "a primera sangre".

> **[a primera sangre](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XCjG7b8#A3FNwML)**
>
> 1. loc. adj. Dicho de un desafío: Que ha de cesar en cuanto uno de los contendientes esté herido.

Te pongo a continuación algunos ejemplos extraídos del CORDE (negritas mías):

> *Todos creíamos que iba a ser un simple lance **a primera sangre**, y se convertía en un lance serio casi a muerte.*
>
> Ramón Gómez de la Serna, "Automoribundia", 1948 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Maneja bien las armas y se bate a menudo, semejante en eso al temerón, pero siempre con fortuna y **a primera sangre**; sus duelos rematan en almuerzo, y son siempre por poca cosa.*
>
> Mariano José de Larra, "Los calaveras. Artículo segundo y conclusión", 1835 (España).

Como ves en este último ejemplo, la expresión tiene ya un par de siglos de antigüedad al menos. En textos más antiguos se pueden encontrar otras formas de la expresión:

> *Dijo el Alguacil:
>
> —Cualquier duelo destos cesa **en habiendo sangre**, y de los dos ya tiene carta de pago.*
>
> Francisco Bernardo de Quirós, "Aventuras de don Fruela", 1656 (España).

Nótese en todo caso que esta expresión se usa para designar a este tipo de duelos. Para el hecho en sí de herir primero a tu oponente, en la literatura ya suelen recurrir a expresiones como "herir primero".

Comment: Carlos, ¿podrías explicar cómo usar el CORDE, o darme un enlace, por favor?

Comment: @aparente001 en la página principal tienes un enlace en la sección "Featured on Meta" con los recursos para aprender español. En esa pregunta tienes una sección titulada ["corpora"](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2519/12637) con los enlaces que buscas.

Answer (score 2):

Encuentro mucho en el internet "sacar primera sangre."  Entonces propongo:

> Dios, yo nunca fui el primero en sacar la pistola
>
> Pero fui el primero en sacar sangre.

Encontré esta frase en un [artículo de deporte](http://hola-arkansas.com/es/sub-23-victoria-completa-para-ee-uu-sobre-mexico/):

> Deteniendo un magnífico gol, Cody Cropper impidió que México fuera el primero en sacar sangre.